# Stationary vs Stability

Tags: time-series, stationarity, vector-autoregression

I am searching for an example of an unstable VAR($p$) process (its reverse characteristic polynomial has no roots inside and on the complex unit circle) which is stationary. I come up with this question as it is often stated in (multivariate) time series analysis that stable (VAR($p$)) processes are stationary, but the reverse is not necessarily true. 
So, what kind of process can be unstable but remains stationary?

Comment: Are you sure that it should not be the other way round? For example, an AR(1) process with coefficient l.t. 1 in absolute value whose error variance changes at some point is stable (which means mean-reverting for me), but not stationary, because its distribution changes over time.

Comment: @ChristophHanck, OP might be correct. it's from Lutkepohl's "Introduction to Multiple Time Series Analysis". I found the citation [here](https://books.google.no/books?id=qJXsCAAAQBAJ&pg=PA20&lpg=PA20&dq=unstable+stationary+process&source=bl&ots=vPRe7sis0Q&sig=YDNtr7afsrKMi-sfSPcYy7XW6hQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CDQQ6AEwA2oVChMIsPqOw8_0yAIVxJQsCh0ksgtp#v=onepage&q=unstable%20stationary%20process&f=false).

Comment: Thanks @ChristophHanck for your comment. I was not aware that there could be a confusion regarding the definition of stability.  I refer to stable VAR($p$) processes defined trough the norm of the roots of the characteristic polynomial. Sorry, I will edit this in my question. As far as I understand your point, this assumption is not fulfilled by an AR(1) process with unit root?

Comment: What I was referring to was the idea that $y_t = \rho y_{t-1}+u_t$ is not stationary if $u_t\sim(0,\sigma_1^2)$ for e.g. $t=1,...,T/2$ and $u_t\sim(0,\sigma_2^2)$ afterwards, because the variance change implies that the unconditional distribution is not independent of $t$. That should be true whether we have an AR or VAR process, and irrespective of whether $\rho$ is less than one in absolute value or not.

Comment: @RichardHardy, thanks for the link, which indeed points in that direction. Lütkepohl rules out my type of counterexample at the beginning of Section 2 by assuming the variance of $u_t$ not to depend on $t$.

Comment: as for your actual question of an unstable but stationary VAR - I do not know

Comment: @ChristophHanck and muffin, what about considering a univariate case with $y_t=-y_{t-1}+\varepsilon_t$. Is it perhaps unstable but stationary? (Generalizing this to multivariate case should be easy.)

Comment: It can happen to be cointegration among the series.